# RxJS How do I mapTo a value that gets reassigned in a do?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm new to RxJS and I'm trying to understand how to manage side effects.

In the following example, I would expect that on each mouse click, an array of random numbers is logged (1 new random number per click). But all I get is an empty array every time, despite the underlying `arr` reference showing the correct value.

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
var arr = [];
var obs = clicks
  .do(() => { arr = arr.concat(Math.random()); })
  .mapTo(arr);
obs.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Clicking around multiple times logs an empty array each time: `[]`

But if I log out `arr`:

```
[0.5336263577508611, 0.8818515430970437, 0.7067802753822072]
```

I get what I exepected.

Interestingly, this works as expected:

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
var arr = [];
var obs = clicks
  .do(() => { arr.push(Math.random()); })
  .mapTo(arr);
obs.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

How come `push`ing to `arr` works, but reassigning it doesn't? It seems like `mapTo` should just return the reference to the `arr` variable.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you use `clicks.mapTo(Math.random())` and then `scan` them to an array?

Answer (score 0):

It is rather about javascript in general: the issue is that by using `arr = arr.concat(…)` you are creating new array each time(without modifying existing one), and saving reference to it into `arr` variable.

But Observable you created holds reference to value `arr` was referencing at moment of observable creation (empty array).

In case when using `arr.push()` - you are not creating new array, but modifying existing one(which was used in `mapTo(arr)`), so observable will emit array with modifications.